# Java grouping values in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, grouping

I have 3 classes:

> 1. Calculation class (includes FinalPrice() method which is return with a double value)
> 2. File Reader class (Load CSV file, split data into an array and return with the first element of the array, which is a String. Includes getType() method)
> 3. Contract class(only contains a constructor)
>
> `File a = new File("D:\\...\\contract.csv");
>         Calculation1 calc = new Calculation1(a);
>         File_Reader1 b = new File_Reader1();
>         Contract c = new Contract(b.getType(a),calc.FinalPrice());`

I need a list to store Contract objects and grouping the keys (which is b.getType(a) ) and sum their values (which is calc.FinalPrice() ), like

Input (for example):

> `list.add("AB", 5);
>    list.add("AC", 8);
>    list.add("AB", 12);`

I would like to get an output like this:

> `"AB" : 17
>   "AC" : 8`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: you could iterate your ArrayList or Map or whatever and in a second list aggregate the value (check with contains() if a key is already in the second list or not) - this is certainly not very performant, but it should work. Depends on how large your list / map should be

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848129/is-there-an-aggregateby-method-in-the-stream-java-8-api

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8,

```
 entries.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
      entry -> entry.getKey(),
      Collectors.summingInt(entry -> entry.getValue())));
```